# Can you have 2 identical COM objects?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, com

A general question that could help answer another question I asked before. I believe that COM objects only return a pointer to the created object. So when I try to initialize a COM object twice, do I make two COM objects in my app, or do I make two different pointers to the same object? or perhaps there are two copies of the object that the pointers point to their respective objects?

```
// Pointer to WebViewController
static wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2Controller> webviewController;

// Pointer to WebView window
static wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2> webviewWindow;


// Locate the browser and set up the environment for WebView
CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions(nullptr, nullptr, nullptr,
    Callback<ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentCompletedHandler>(
        [hWnd, url](HRESULT result, ICoreWebView2Environment* env) -> HRESULT {

    // Create a CoreWebView2Controller and get the associated CoreWebView2 whose parent is the main window hWnd
    env->CreateCoreWebView2Controller(hWnd, Callback<ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2ControllerCompletedHandler>(
        [hWnd, url](HRESULT result, ICoreWebView2Controller* controller) -> HRESULT {

        _com_error err4(result);
        MessageBoxW(hWnd, L"Controller setup", 0, MB_OK);
        MessageBoxW(hWnd, err4.ErrorMessage(), 0, MB_OK);

        if (controller != nullptr) {
            webviewController = controller;
            webviewController->get_CoreWebView2(&webviewWindow);
        }

        // Add a few settings for the webview
        // The demo step is redundant since the values are the default settings
        ICoreWebView2Settings* Settings;
        webviewWindow->get_Settings(&Settings);
        Settings->put_IsScriptEnabled(TRUE);
        Settings->put_AreDefaultScriptDialogsEnabled(TRUE);
        Settings->put_IsWebMessageEnabled(TRUE);

        // Resize WebView to fit the bounds of the parent window
        RECT bounds;
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &bounds);
        webviewController->put_Bounds(bounds);

        // Schedule an async task to navigate to Bing
        webviewWindow->Navigate(url);
        if (GetWindow(hWnd, GW_CHILD) != NULL) {
            MessageBoxW(hWnd, L"not a NULL child window", 0, MB_OK);
        };

        // Step 4 - Navigation events

        // Step 5 - Scripting

        // Step 6 - Communication between host and web content

        return S_OK;
    }).Get());
    return S_OK;
}).Get());
```

I called
`CoInitialize(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);` earlier in the code only once. My question is what happens when I run this block twice?

Comment: You could determine this empirically by calling the function twice and comparing the two pointers you get back.

Comment: @jon That's not how COM objects are compared for identity. All comparison operations require that you first query for the canonical `IUnknown`, and only then are you able to compare the pointers for equality in a meaningful way.

Comment: It's not clear what problem you are trying to solve. COM makes promises about interfaces and the lifetimes of objects behind those interfaces. Object lifetimes are guaranteed to be *"long enough"*. It's equally unclear, how `CoInitializeEx` is involved in any of this. As [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-coinitializeex) it *"must be called at least once"*. Once that's done, you can run arbitrary blocks of code using COM an arbitrary number of times.

Comment: @IInspectable Two pointers to the same interface should be the same for the same object, I think that's one of the fundamental rules of COM?

Comment: @jon Checking for object identity still requires that you first query for the `IUnknown` interface, even if you hold interface pointers to the same interface. Comparing `IUnknown` pointers for equality is the only meaningful pointer comparison specified by COM. Everything else is outside COM's specification. Anything can happen.

Comment: @IInspectable I think this is a semantic issue more than anything else. One of the COM requirements is that if you query a given object for an interface (e.g. IInspectable) multiple times, the address should be the same every time. It therefore stands to reason that if you have two pointers that are the same, they refer to the same object, irrespective of the interface they represent.

Comment: @JonathanPotter - This is only a COM requirement for IUnknown: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/rules-for-implementing-queryinterface#objects-must-have-identity

Comment: @jon You are confusing *"something that sounds plausible to you"* with fundamental COM rules. I have explained what the fundamental COM rule is, and Simon provided the link to documentation.

Comment: If you have two pointers that point to the same address how can they possibly be different objects? Be sensible.

Comment: @jon Stop trying to right your wrong. Pointer comparisons in COM are meaningful for pointers to `IUnknown` and pointers to `IUnknown` only. Every other pointer comparison is meaningless no matter how much you want them to be meaningful. Getting the `IUnknown` for any interface costs you one statement or one expression depending on whether you want to avoid using a smart pointer library. Do you really want to save one statement or expression? Be sensible.

Comment: Well all I can say is I would love to see sample code that can implement two different objects at the same address.

Comment: @jon Like, a `union`, or [this C++20 footgun](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address)? Sure, that sample is trivial. But you are failing to acknowledge the flip side of things: What if the pointers aren't the same? As written, your comment strongly suggests that those interface pointers point at different object instances. That conclusion isn't backed by COM's rules.

Comment: @IInspectable, The problem I'm trying to solve is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68089327/how-do-you-use-webviewwindow-navigate-from-outside-the-initialization-of-th). I am currently trying to figure out a way to have only one Webview2 object and refer back to it whenever I need to navigate to a new page. I currently have it calling the entire function above every time I need it to navigate, but someone more knowledgeable than I mentioned that this would most likely make multiple instances rather Navigating the original object.

Comment: You don't need an answer to this question to solve *that* problem. Just do as you're doing. This requires that you understand object lifetimes and the order in which MFC calls into your callbacks. Clearly, you are trying to access `webviewWindow` before it has been assigned to. The quick fix: `if (!webviewWindow) {/* report error */} else {/* use webviewWindow */}`. The real fix is to learn MFC. Learning MFC is substantially harder than learning the flat Windows API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is what happens when I run this block twice?

In this specific case, executing the code twice will produce two distinct WebView2 instances. Both instances are then assigned to the same `static` variable, causing one instance to be irrevocably leaked.

Being an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info) this information isn't terribly useful. The real issue you are trying to solve is knowing when the WebView2 control is fully constructed. That question has been answered [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68089327/1889329).

Answer (score 2):

> So when I try to initialize a COM object twice, do I make two COM objects in my app, or do I make two different pointers to the same object? or perhaps there are two copies of the object that the pointers point to their respective objects?

That really depends on the implementation of the COM object.  If it is implemented as a singleton, then instantiating it multiple times will return a pointer to the existing instance (creating a new instance if it doesn't exist yet).  But, if the COM object is not implemented as a singleton, then each instantiation will return a pointer to a new instance.

Comment: I haven't worked much with COM objects, and am only familiar with singletons in C#. But thanks for the tip. I'll be looking into singletons, I am trying to search for posts of WebView2 with MFC.